# Jenkins Amazon Linux Setup

Tags: linux, jenkins, deployment, amazon-ec2

I have setup jenkins on my ec2 instance using the below steps from a tutorial online. I am novice in linux environment and deployments. My problem is that the jenkins dashboard is not showing up in browser at <myIp>:8080/jenkins. Can someone help me out for this.

```
sudo yum install -y docker nginx git

sudo wget -O /etc/yum.repos.d/jenkins.repo http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/redhat/jenkins.repo

sudo rpm --import https://jenkins-ci.org/redhat/jenkins-ci.org.key

sudo yum install jenkins

sudo vim /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
Change as below
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  _;

    location /jenkins {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    }
}

sudo usermod -a -G docker jenkins

sudo service docker start
sudo service jenkins start
sudo service nginx start
sudo chkconfig docker on
sudo chkconfig jenkins on
sudo chkconfig nginx on
```

Comment: Check the security group of the instance

Comment: That solved it! I added the Custom TCP Rule in security group for port 8080. Thank you @HussainZKathawala

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had faced similar problem before, you can check following:

- Check security groups of the instance for specific ports
- Check IP tables on the instance

Hope that helps